# Store and access billions tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to work with a huge dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = 
{
    (123, 456, 789): 1,
    (3455, 5, 45): 345,
    (689, 273, 1294): 3457,
[...]
}
```

(this dictionary stores spacial position of different object identifiers by integer)

One of the requirements is to access it (lots of reading, sometimes writing) as quickly as possible. What can I use to store it? Using a dict variable looks like a bad idea. Should I use a NoSQL Database? Which one is optimized for simple data like this dictionary ?

Second requirement is python 3.x.

*About usage of these tuples*: When i need to use this dic, i want the value of some tuples. E.g.:

```
wanted_positions = [(123, 456, 789), (3455, 5, 45), (55, 567, 247), (75, 587, 4523)]
objects_in_positions = [d[pos] for pos in wanted_positions]
```

Comment: What is "huge"? Also, this is subjective as it depends on the exact operations that you wish to perform. How soon after writing should a valuable be available for reading?

Comment: You can use a `CSV` file! for store your tuples!

Comment: @SimeonVisser i have ~1 billions positions to store. Writed data have to be available just after write.

Comment: I will edit to add precisions about how i want to use these tuples.

Comment: @SimeonVisser precisions added.

Comment: is there a pattern? if so use a function.

Comment: If you have enough memory (and don't need to worry about data persistence), a Python dictionary should be plenty fast. It uses a hash table, which means lookups are, on average `O(1)` time regardless of the number of elements.

Comment: Spatial data? Use a format and tools optimized for spatial data then. For example [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) or [shapefiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile). You might also want to have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: RE your usage example, the tuples in `wanted_positions` are guaranteed to be keys of your dictionary?